# Django: how do i substract numbers from another number and return the new_value in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a model field called `main_all_earning` and it looks like this `main_all_earning = models.IntegerField(default=0)`, I also have a form where user are allowed to input any amount they want to withdraw from `main_all_earning`, I have written the logic for it to subtract the value from the form which is called `amount` from the `main_all_earning`, but the main_all_earning does not update. What could be the issue?

Views.py:

```
def withdrawal_request(request):
    user = request.user
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
    main_all_earning = profile.main_all_earning
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = WithWithdrawalRequestForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_form = form.save(commit=False)
            new_form.user = request.user
            if ...:
                pass
            else:
                new_form.save()
                main_all_earning = main_all_earning - new_form.amount
                return redirect("core:withdrawal-request")
    else:
        ...
    context = { "form":form, "main_all_earning":main_all_earning,}
    return render(request, "core/withdrawal-request.html", context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the `main_all_earning` variable here:

```py
main_all_earning = main_all_earning - new_form.amount
```

But you don't actually set it on the profile or save it:

```py
profile.main_all_earning = main_all_earning - new_form.amount
profile.save()
```